# Does 12.04 support the Dell Perc 6i RAID card?

Tags: server, hardware, raid, drivers

I have a Dell Perc 6i RAID card currently used under Win 2K3 and I am going to transit to Ubuntu Server 12. Since Dell only provides driver for Ubuntu 10 Server yet Dell servers with this RAID card are certified in Ubuntu website. I am wondering if I can get this RAID card work under Ubuntu Server 12. Does anybody have similiar problems?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, the Dell Perc6 series is officially supported by Ubuntu

The Dell Perc 6-series cards are rebranded LSI Megaraid cards [with the LSI1078 chipset](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftrac.biostr.washington.edu%2Ftrac%2Fwiki%2FMegaRaid&ei=btPrT9ycNqPc2gW2o9jbAQ&usg=AFQjCNFbLfKhYeGOwco5jMPPFu6YsIRsFA&sig2=d0oHktCzTb75btbWiGbrGg). The drivers for LSI Megaraid in Ubuntu have been stable for a very long time, and [**specifically support the Dell 6 series**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man4/mfi.4freebsd.html):

> The mfi driver supports the following hardware:

```
 
     +o   LSI MegaRAID SAS 1078
     +o   LSI MegaRAID SAS 8408E
     +o   LSI MegaRAID SAS 8480E
     +o   LSI MegaRAID SAS 9260
     +o   Dell PERC5
     +o   Dell PERC6
     +o   IBM ServeRAID M5015 SAS/SATA
     +o   IBM ServeRAID-MR10i
     +o   Intel RAID Controller SROMBSAS18E
```

I have a Megaraid 8408E and Ubuntu Server 12.04 has been working fantastically with it.

Comment: I have MegaRAID SAS 1078, and it's not working in Ubuntu. Ubuntu also doesn't work from the USB 3.0 stick (needs 2.0). Fedora works just fine out of the box, however.